# Cant Run my headless automation script on the server (stacktrace)

Tags: server, robotframework, headless-browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MTnu.png)I am getting this error when running my headless in my server
Server: MAC mini M1
Chrome Version = 114.0.5735.198
ChromeDriver Version= 114.0.5735.90

Here is my Code:

```
*** Variable ***
${CHROMEDRIVER_PATH}= /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

*** Keywords ***
Open On Headless Browser 2
    [Arguments]    ${driver}    ${URL}
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --test-type
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --enable-javascript
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --incognito
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-notifications
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --new-window
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --aggressive-cache-discard
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-application-cache
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --mute-audio
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    useAutomationExtension    ${False}
    Open Browser    ${URl}    chrome    options=${chrome_options}      executable_path=${CHROMEDRIVER_PATH}
    Set Window Size    1920    1080
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${search_txt}
    Capture Page Screenshot    picture1.png
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${login_btn}    timeout=10
    Capture Page Screenshot    picture1.png
```

it can detect the search_txt but not the login_btn which on the upper left corner while the search_txt is on the upper middle. I already set the window size to 1920x1080 and it also cant capture screenshot to check if the browser really open wide. it work perfectly fine on my local(windows) but not on the server.

Those anyone encounter this?
Please Help me.
Many Thanks